# Faster way to calculate percentage?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently use this method to come up with a percentage:

```
declare @height table
(
    UserId int,
    tall bit
)
insert into @height
select  1, 1 union all
select  2, 1 union all 
select 6, 0 union all
select  3, 0 union all 
select 7, 0 union all
select  4, 1 union all 
select 8, 0 union all
select  5, 0

declare @all decimal(8,5)

select 
    @all = count(distinct UserId)
from @height

select 
    count(distinct UserId) / @all Pct
from @height
where tall = 1
```

**Result: 0.375000000**

Is there a better performing way to do this?  As you can see the `@height`

table is hit twice.

Thanks!

Comment: Cant the `UserId` field really contain more than one of the same ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This allows you to hit the table only once, and gives you the same result for your given dataset.

```
declare @height table
(
    UserId int,
    tall bit
)
insert into @height
select  1, 1 union all
select  2, 1 union all 
select 6, 0 union all
select  3, 0 union all 
select 7, 0 union all
select  4, 1 union all 
select 8, 0 union all
select  5, 0


select SUM(convert(decimal(8,5), tall)) / convert(decimal(8,5), COUNT(*)) Pct
from @height
```

Depending on your requirements, this might work for duplicate userids. At least it gives the same result as yours does.

```
select SUM(convert(decimal(8,5), tall)) / convert(decimal(8,5), COUNT(distinct userid)) Pct
from 
    (select distinct UserId, tall
    from @height) t
```

Comment: There will def. be dups in the real table (totally different schema).  I'm not a big fan of subqueries, perhaps a cte would be better?

Comment: @subt13 - This is not a subquery, it is a derived table. But that is a subtle point that some would disagree with. Regardless, why no love for subqueries? I guess if you can't find it in your heart to embrace the syntax, then rewrite it as a CTE. CTE syntax is more complex than this IMHO.

Comment: Haha, no matter. Your answer has given me the opportunity to decide that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative query that produces your expected results.  I don't know how the performance of this query compares to others, but I suspect it would be easy enough for you to test this.

```
declare @height table
(
    UserId int,
    tall bit
)
insert into @height
select  1, 1 union all
select  2, 1 union all 
select  4, 1 union all 

select  3, 0 union all 
select  5, 0 union all
select  6, 0 union all
select  7, 0 union all
select  8, 0

Select 1.0 * Count(Distinct Case When Tall = 1 Then UserId End) 
       / Count(Distinct UserId)
From   @height
```